# Chaining promises with Thunk and Promise middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, redux-thunk

I am using both `redux-promise-middleware` and `redux-thunk` like this:

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import logger from 'redux-logger'

import reducer from './reducers'

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, promise(), logger({diff: true}));
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const enhancer = composeEnhancers(middleware);

export default createStore(
    reducer,
    enhancer)
```

So, what I'd like to do is chain a couple promises together. The `redux-promise-middleware` documentation recommends using `Promise.all` like this:

```
export function startTest(test) {
    return dispatch => {
        return dispatch({
            type: START_TEST,
            id: test,
            payload: Promise.all([
                dispatch(axios.post(urlJoin(config.portalUrl, 'account/login')))
            ])
        })
    };
}
```

However, when I dispatch this to the store I get the following error:

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

What did I configure wrong?

Comment: Why do you call `Promise.all` on an array with a single value?

Comment: @Bergi it's because I'll be executing more in the future as I chain them; I just needed to get that architecture working is all. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. It needed changed to something like this:

```
export function startTest(test) {
    return dispatch => {
        return dispatch({
            type: START_TEST_THUNK,
            payload: Promise.all([
                dispatch({
                    type: START_TEST,
                    payload: axios.post(urlJoin(config.portalUrl, 'account/login')),
                    meta: {
                        id: test
                    }
                })
            ])
        })
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a direct answer to your question**, but you don't really need to use the `redux-promise-middleware` package. You can simply create your own middleware to handle promises. This is my simple implementation of the Promise Middleware:

```
export default function PromiseMiddleware() {
   return (next) => (action) => {
      const {promise, type, ...rest} = action

      if (!promise) return next(action)

      const REQUEST = type + '_REQUEST'
      const SUCCESS = type + '_SUCCESS'
      const FAILURE = type + '_FAILURE'

      next({...rest, type: REQUEST})

      return promise
         .then(result => {

            next({...rest, result, type: SUCCESS})

            return true
         })
         .catch(error => {
            if (DEBUG) {
               console.error(error)
               console.log(error.stack)
            }
            next({...rest, error, type: FAILURE})

            return false
         })
   }
}
```

And you can apply it exactly like you have done:

```
const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, PromiseMiddleware, logger({diff: true}))
```